# how to use module in same module file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

aUtil.js

```
module.exports = {
    successTrue: function(data) { 
        return { data: data, success: true };
    },
    isLoggedin: async (req, res) { 
        //decoded token in req header
        //if decoded token success, 
        res.json(this.successTrue(req.decoded));
    }
}
```

that function call in test.js

```
router.get('/check', aUtil.isLoggedin, async (req, res) => { ... })
```

I want to use the function above in that function.

But I keep getting errors.

```
ReferenceError: successTrue is not defined
```

I tried many ways.

1. insert 'const aUtil = require('./aUtil')`
2. change to `'res.json(successTrue( ... )'`

Comment: a little suggestion please use ```exports.successTrue = function () { }``` this is alot more cleaner

Comment: @AfrazAhmad That's subjective. For one I don't think it's cleaner at all.

Comment: `isLoggedin` doesn't need to be `async` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this`:

```
module.exports = {
    successTrue: function() {
      return { foo: 'bar' } 
    },

    isLoggedin: function() {
      console.log(this.successTrue())
    }
}
```

You're exporting an object, so `this` refers to itself.

Also make sure you're binding `aUtils` if you're using it as middleware like so:

`router.get('/check', aUtil.isLoggedin.bind(aUtil), async (req, res) => { ... })`

Comment: I tried the same way, but I got an error. 'TypeError: this.successTrue is not a function'

Comment: How are you calling `aUtil.isLoggedin`? Edit your post to add the relevant code.

Comment: The function name was typed incorrectly. successTrue is right. I modified it.

Comment: The same concept stands. You should do: `res.json(this.successTrue(req.decoded))`

Comment: That's the old code, and I've corrected it when I saw your answer, but there's an error.

Comment: You can't be getting this error `ReferenceError: successTrue is not defined` with the code I gave you. Also post the code that calls `aUtil.isLoggedin`.

Comment: i post it. Please check it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: a little suggestion please use ```exports.successTrue = function () { }``` this is alot more cleaner

Comment: @HyunJin See my edit on how to call `aUtil.isLoggedin`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
const aUtil = {
    successTrue: function() { //return json obj },
    isLoggedin: function() { 
        res.json(aUtil.successTrue( ... ));
    }
}
module.exports = aUtil;
```